# RSpec Uniqueness Test Failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm building some test for user account creation, and am running into an issue with one of my tests.  The test is supposed to verify that the username cannot be used more than one time, and for some reason the test is failing, even though the behavior is working as expected in the actual application itself.

What's strange is I have a similar test set up to prevent duplicate email addresses, and that test is actually working as expected.  Since they're set up very similarly, I'm surprised one is working but the other is not.

I'm posting the entire test file, as well as the model and migration files, below. The specific test that's failing is the fifth test, "test duplicate username."  If there are any other files I can provide that may help in troubleshooting this issue.

RSpec Test File:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  # initiate new users
  let(:user) {User.new}
  let(:user1) {User.new}

  # test new account without username
  it "is not valid without a username" do
    expect(user).not_to be_valid
  end

  # test username min length
  it "must have at least 5 chars in username" do
    user.username = 'a' * 4
    expect(user).not_to be_valid
  end

  # test username max length
  it "must have fewer than 25 chars in username" do
    user.username = 'a' * 26
    expect(user).not_to be_valid
  end

  # test proper username length
  it "must have between 5-25 chars in username" do
    user.username = 'a' * 6
    expect(user).to be_valid
  end

  # test duplicate usernames
    it "cannot use the same username multiple times" do
        user.username = 'aBCDEF'
        user1.username = 'aBCDEF'
        expect(user1).not_to be_valid
    end

  # test password min length
    it "must have at least 6 chars in password" do
        user.password = 'a' * 5
        expect(user).not_to be_valid
    end

    #test password max length
    it "must have no more than 25 chars in password" do
        user.password = 'a' * 26
        expect(user).not_to be_valid
  end

  # test multiple email addresses
    it "cannot use the same email multiple times" do
        user.email = 'dan@dan.com'
        user1.email = 'dan@dan.com'
        expect(user1).not_to be_valid
    end

end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  USERNAME_LENGTH = (5..25)
  PASSWORD_LENGTH = (6..25)

  validates_presence_of :username
  validates :username, length: USERNAME_LENGTH, uniqueness: true 
  validates :password, length: PASSWORD_LENGTH, allow_nil: true
  validates :email, uniqueness: true

  has_many :posts
  has_one :cart

  attr_reader :password

  def self.find_from_credentials(username, password)
    user = find_by(username: username)
    return nil unless user
    user if user.is_password?(password)
  end

  def is_password?(password_attempt)
    BCrypt::Password.new(password_digest).is_password?(password_attempt)
  end

  def password=(password)
    @password = password
    self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(password)
  end
end
```

User Migration File:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :session_token
      t.string :password_digest
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.boolean :admin

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :username
    add_index :users, :session_token

  end
end
```

Comment: If you save first your first user, it'd make the test pass, but this'd lead us on asking why isn't needed to save the first user on testing the email uniqueness to make the test pass.

Comment: if you see the test.log you can see the uniqueness query. uniqueness always will be checked with already existing records in database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test fails specifically because you've added a validation on the presence of the username, and in that example, you're not adding emails nor for `user` or `user1`.

See:

```
it "cannot use the same email multiple times" do
    user.email = 'dan@dan.com'
    user1.email = 'dan@dan.com'
    expect(user1).not_to be_valid
end
```

There if you check the validity of user1 before the expectation you'll see

```
user1.valid?          # false
user1.errors.messages # {:username=>["can't be blank"]}
```

So it doesn't fail because of the uniqueness validation, but for the absence of an username.

Be sure on saving your records before testing them. In both cases Rails will check in the database if there's a record with the same attribute and give you the boolean result of the operation.

Let's move to the rails console and check with persisted data:

Suppose you have an user:

```
User.where(username: 'foo')
# [#<User:0x00007ff65cff14f0 id: 1, username: "foo", email: "foo@bar.com", ...]
```

Now do the attempt to create  a new one, with the same username:

```
bar = User.new(username: 'foo')
bar.valid? # false
# User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
# User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = ? LIMIT ?  [["username", "foo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
bar.errors.messages # {:username=>["has already been taken"]}
```

Now the same but without records with username "foo":

```
User.where(username: 'foo')
# []
bar.valid? # true
User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = ? LIMIT ?  [["username", "foo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

So, you need to save your first user everytime you're checking for uniqueness to have something which to compare with.

This might help as an example:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  let(:user) { User.new(email: 'foo@bar.com', username: 'foo') }
  before { user.save }

  context 'username uniqueness' do
    let(:user1) { User.new(email: 'bar@foo.com', username: 'foo') }

    it { expect(user1).to_not be_valid }
  end

  context 'email uniqueness' do
    let(:user1) { User.new(email: 'foo@bar.com', username: 'bar') }

    it { expect(user1).to_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Sebastian, but I'm afraid I'm a little confused by it.  The test that you're quoting is a separate test for duplicate email accounts, and is running without any issue.  There's an earlier test in the file that says "it cannot use the same username multiple times", and that's the one that's failing.  You'll notice that in the test there, I am populating the username field and not the email field.  If there's something else that I may be missing where this email test is somehow tied to the username test, would you mind clarifying?

Comment: Also, I have tried populating the database with a sample username and tried to create an account with the same username in my test, but it continues to fail.  I also believe I have the uniqueness set up properly for the username field the same way I do for the email one in the model, but maybe I'm missing something there?

Comment: See your example, the one I pointed in the answer, there you test the user1 isn't valid, and right, isn't valid, but not because of the uniqueness, but because it doesn't have an username. What you need to do is set their specific attributes before each test and save them. If you test for email uniqueness, set each user with an username and equal emails, save the first one then you can check if the second one is valid or not.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  I incorporated those changes and that got the test to pass.  My last question is why that before { user.save } line is necessary.  Does that basically tell the system to save the User name after the username/email have been populated?

Comment: Glad it worked. Everything what's inside a `before` block is executed before each example, so it's saving your first user before each example to have data which to use to check the uniqueness. It allows you to remove duplicated lines, but you can remove it if is needed. As I had just two examples I used it, because both needed an user in the db. Would recommend you having a look to [this](https://jacopretorius.net/2017/04/validate-uniqueness-in-rails.html) article.